# Why can't I plot anything with ParametricPlot3D?

Tags: plotting, numerical-integration, graphics3d

Code:

```
 sol = NDSolve[{-1* (1+2* Sin[\[Beta][t]]) (2 *2* Cos[\[Beta][t]] *\[Alpha]'[t] *\[Beta]'[t]+(1+2* Sin[\[Beta][t]]) *\[Alpha]''[t])==0,2* 1*(9.81* Sin[\[Beta][t]]+Cos[\[Beta][t]] (1+2* Sin[\[Beta][t]]) *(\[Alpha]'[t])^2-2*\[Beta]''[t]) == 0 , \[Alpha][0]==1, \[Alpha]'[0]==1, \[Beta][0]==2, \[Beta]'[0]==2}, {\[Alpha][t], \[Beta][t]}, {t, 0, 10}, MaxSteps-> 100000];

 a[t_] = \[Alpha][t] /. sol;
 b[t_] = \[Beta][t] /. sol;

 ParametricPlot3D[{(1 + 1*Sin[Evaluate[b[t]]])*Cos[Evaluate[a[t]]], (1 + 1 * Sin[Evaluate[b[t]]])*Sin[Evaluate[a[t]]],1 * Cos[Evaluate[b[t]]] }, {t, 0, 10},PlotRange -> All]
```

It should theoretically work, but it doesn't show anything. Why?

Comment: Using `First` or  [[1]]  `a[t_] = \[Alpha][t] /. sol[[1]];
b[t_] = \[Beta][t] /. sol[[1]];`

Comment: Thanks a lot! :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is recommend to use `sol` as the `Rule` to replace the `α[t]` and `β[t]`,then we need not define a new function `a[t]` and `b[t]`.

```
sol = NDSolve[{-1*(1 + 
        2*Sin[β[t]]) (2*2*
         Cos[β[t]]*α'[t]*β'[
          t] + (1 + 2*Sin[β[t]])*α''[t]) == 0, 
    2*1*(9.81*Sin[β[t]] + 
        Cos[β[t]] (1 + 2*Sin[β[t]])*(α'[t])^2 - 
        2*β''[t]) == 0, α[0] == 1, α'[0] == 
     1, β[0] == 2, β'[0] == 2}, {α[t], β[
     t]}, {t, 0, 10}, MaxSteps -> 100000];
ParametricPlot3D[{(1 + 1*Sin[β[t]])*
    Cos[α[t]], (1 + 1*Sin[β[t]])*Sin[α[t]], 
   1*Cos[β[t]]} /. sol, {t, 0, 10}, PlotRange -> All]
```

[image]